# SwiftUI change and animate foreground color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm new to swiftUI and I am trying to I have a blue view flash green for half a second and then go back to blue. I've tried multiple ways. I have tried setting the color to a state variable but that does not work. In the current code below the view just remains blue. [Current implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoGdw.png)

Comment: post your code ... instead of image

Comment: have you tried the solution i provided ?

Comment: Sorry about that, next time I will post code instead of an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with State Variable

```
@State private var color = Color.red
  var body: some View {

      Circle()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .foregroundColor(color)
      .onAppear {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 4)) {
           self.color = Color.blue

        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.0) {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 4)){self.color = Color.red }
        }


    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried the code and it somewhat works. The only thing is that it now stays blue and I need it to go back to its original color.

Comment: Okay i will do that

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this out but it seems to be skipping over the first animation.

```
@State private var color = Color.blue

var body: some View {
    Circle()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    .foregroundColor(color)
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {
                self.color = Color.green
            }
            withAnimation(
                Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2)
                    .delay(2)
                ) {
                self.color = Color.blue
            }
    }
}
```